# Equivalent of .NET's System.Xml.XmlWriter - in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I want something proven and tested (e.g. apache commons level of maturity) not some code snippet from the [first search result in Google](http://www.generationjava.com/docs/XmlWriter/XmlWriter.java.html)

Or is [GenerationJava](http://www.generationjava.com/projects/GenJavaCore.shtml) not the abandonware it seems to be (the [download](http://www.osjava.org/releases/official/genjava-core/) link and the referal to the new host - [osjava.org](http://www.osjava.org/genjava-core/)  are both 404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [StAX](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3669/bnbgx?a=view)?

Example from the link:

```
xtw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
xtw.writeComment("all elements here are explicitly in the HTML namespace");
xtw.writeStartDocument("utf-8","1.0");
xtw.setPrefix("html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40");
xtw.writeStartElement("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40","html");
xtw.writeNamespace("html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40");
xtw.writeStartElement("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40","head");
xtw.writeStartElement("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40","title");
xtw.writeCharacters("Frobnostication");
xtw.writeEndElement();
xtw.writeEndElement();
xtw.writeStartElement("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40","body");
xtw.writeStartElement("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40","p");
xtw.writeCharacters("Moved to");
xtw.writeStartElement("http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40","a");
xtw.writeAttribute("href","http://frob.com");
xtw.writeCharacters("here");
xtw.writeEndElement();
xtw.writeEndElement();
xtw.writeEndElement();
xtw.writeEndElement();
xtw.writeEndDocument();
xtw.flush();
xtw.close();
```